# Unable to use mongoose virtual with typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to learn how to use virtuals with mongoose and typescript.

Say I have an interface for a user.

```
interface User {
    id: mongoose.ObjectId;
    name: string;
    likes: string;
}
```

Then I create a schema for mongoose.

```js
// create the model
const user: mongoose.SchemaDefinition<User> = {
    name: { type: String },
    likes: { type: String },
};

// enable the use of virtuals
const options: mongoose.SchemaOptions = {
    toJSON: { getters: true, virtuals: true },
    toObject: { virtuals: true },
};

// create the scheme
const schema = new Schema(user, options);
```

Then I go to add a virtual and create my model.

```js
// attach the virtual "bio" to return a string about the user
schema.virtual("bio").get(function (): string {
    return `Hi my name is ${this.name} and i like ${this.likes}`;
});

const model = mongoose.model("User", schema);
```

However, creating the virtual like above produces this error on `this`. See below picture.

[image]

So I thought that I could modify my virtual based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54445462/mongoose-virtuals-with-typescript-error-the-containing-arrow-function-captures).

```js
schema.virtual("bio").get(function (this: User): string {
    return `Hi my name is ${this.name} and i like ${this.likes}`;
});

const model = mongoose.model("User", schema);
```

However this does not work for me because my theory is that the following is set in my tsconfig `"noUnusedLocals": true`. I don't wan't to disable this because its a helpful linting rule. See below picture.

[image]

So my question is how can I create a mongoose virtual in typescript that does not throw an error like this, is there a simple example somewhere that I have missed while googling?

I guess one solution is to add `// eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars` to the line above to suppress the warning. However that does not explain why `this` is "unused". Even though it is.

I have even tried specifically using `this` by setting it to temporary variables (which get IntelliSense for the User interface, so its not like its ignoring the typing).

```js
schema.virtual("bio").get(function (this: IUserModel): string {
    const name = this.name;
    const like = this.likes;
    return `Hi my name is ${name} and i like ${like}`;
});
```

Here's my full example as one copy-paste-friendly blob.

```js
interface User {
    id: mongoose.ObjectId;
    name: string;
    likes: string;
}

const user: mongoose.SchemaDefinition<User> = {
    name: { type: String },
    likes: { type: String },
};

const options: mongoose.SchemaOptions = {
    toJSON: { getters: true, virtuals: true },
    toObject: { virtuals: true },
};

const schema = new Schema(user, options);

// this is defined but never used :(
schema.virtual("bio").get(function (this: User): string {
    return `Hi my name is ${this.name} and i like ${this.likes}`;
});

const model = mongoose.model("User", schema);

export default model;
```

Comment: Not sure why this didn't work for you, – it worked perfectly for me (see https://tsplay.dev/wOzxzW)

Comment: Maybe, the problem is that you're using `new Schema()` instead of `new mongoose.Schema()` (everything else it prepended with `mongoose.` though), and it unexpectedly resolves to some other existing class, unrelated to mongoose?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set these properties if you're working on typescript

```
user.set("toObject", { virtuals: true });
user.set("toJSON", { virtuals: true });
```