# How to use Schema.virtual in typescript?

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, mongoose, mern

I was using schema.virtual  property in js but now i want to use it with tyescript and getting error.
this is my code

```
UserSchema.virtual('fullname').get(function () {
  return `${this.firstName} ${this.lastName}`
});
```

I am facing this error

```
this' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few solutions to work around this specific problem, for example [declaring an interface](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66012890/893780) for typing `this`, but in my experience this will create other issues (one being that `doc.fullname` will cause an error because TS isn't smart enough to know `fullname` has been added as a virtual).

The easiest way to solve this is to make virtuals part of the Schema declaration:

```
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  firstName : String,
  lastName  : String,
  ...
}, {
  virtuals : {
    fullname : {
      get() {
        return `${this.firstName} ${this.lastName}`;
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Its not working even on js project, in js project its doing nothing 
and in TS app its throwing error

Comment: This is working fine in TypeScript for me. What's the exact error that you get? How are you using this virtual (or what does it need to do)?

Comment: I am getting these errors on typescript as shown in image :https://imgur.com/a/rvqHkNK

Comment: Which version of Mongoose are you using? I'm using 6.6.2 which has `virtuals` defined in the `SchemaOptions` type.

Comment: mine is         "mongoose": "^6.0.12",

Comment: I updated version to 6.6.2 and not i am not getting any error.  but now the problem is I am not getting fullname in the response

Comment: Why you don't get `fullname` in the response is explained [in the fine manual](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#virtuals). Look for `toJSON`.

Comment: Its solved, Thank you soo much man, U so lovely.
I was missing toJson and toObject virtuals :true thing